# Sharing data between two modules MeanJs not working

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I have investigated this issue for couple of hours without success. Definitely i am missing something here.

I want to be able to share information between two modules that i have created. So basically the first module is the user module that comes along with MeanJs the other module is generated using yo meanjs generator. Have a look below to my code.

This is the product module:

```
angular.module('products').factory('Productplan', [
   function() {
    return {
        someMethod: function() {
            return "I am Working!";
        }
    };
}
```

]);

This is the users module:

```
angular.module('users').controller('AuthenticationController', ['$scope', 'Productplan',
function($scope, Productplan) {
    console.log(Productplan.someMethod());
}
```

]);

This is the error generated by this issue:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: ProductplanProvider <- Productplan
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Change your user module from**

```
angular.module('users')
```

**to**

```
angular.module('users',['products'])
```

Comment: i have tried and the app route does not work when i add ['products'], it redirects you to homepage. I mean it should work but i am starting to think that in meanjs maybe things work differently.